# Why getsockopt optlen is zero?

Tags: c, sockets, getsockopt

I use nonblocking sockets and event library with it. I just noticed when I call connect rapidly to my local ip's ports randomly `getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &val, &optlen);`'s optlen becomes 0.

I tried to make smaller code that's able to show problem. I used epoll in this code but same problem happens in other event libraries too.

```
#define nconnect_d 500
#define ebuffer_d 64

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

struct sockaddr_in initaddr(uint32_t ip, uint16_t port){
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip);
    memset(addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(addr.sin_zero));
    return addr;
}

int getconnectfd(uint32_t sip, uint16_t sport, uint32_t dip, uint16_t dport){
    int fd;
    if((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        return -1;
    if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (int[]){1}, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        return -1;
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
        return -1;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr = initaddr(sip, sport);
    if(bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
        return -1;
    struct sockaddr_in daddr = initaddr(dip, dport);
    if(connect(fd, (const struct sockaddr*)&daddr, (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1 && errno != EINPROGRESS)
        return -1;
    return fd;
}

int epolltouch(int efd, int sfd, uint32_t flag){
    struct epoll_event event;
    event.data.fd = sfd;
    event.events = flag;
    if(epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &event) == -1)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int epollrm(int efd, int sfd){
    if(epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sfd, NULL) == -1)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int efd = epoll_create1(0);
    assert(efd != -1);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < nconnect_d; i++){
        int sfd = getconnectfd(INADDR_ANY, 12420, 0x7f000001, 2048 + i);
        assert(sfd != -1);
        epolltouch(efd, sfd, EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET);
    }
    struct epoll_event events[ebuffer_d];
    uint32_t iconnect = nconnect_d;
    while(iconnect){
        int n = epoll_wait(efd, events, ebuffer_d, -1);
        assert(n != -1);
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int evfd = events[i].data.fd;
            int opt, optlen;
            assert(getsockopt(evfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &opt, &optlen) != -1);
            assert(optlen == sizeof(int));
            switch(opt){
                case 0:{
                    /* connection has been established */
                    break;
                }
                case ECONNREFUSED:
                case EHOSTUNREACH:
                case ENETUNREACH:
                /* can be more valid case isn't it? */
                {
                    /* connection has failed */
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    assert(0);
                }
            }
            iconnect--;
            epollrm(efd, evfd);
            close(evfd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run;

```
$ ./a.out
a.out: temp.c:72: main: Assertion `optlen == sizeof(int)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is optlen 0 means socket is closed with some reason? Do we need to close socket after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getsockopt()` requires that you provide the buffer to the system, and that means you have to set the `optlen` before the call:

```
int opt;
socklen_t optlen = sizeof opt;

... getsockopt(evfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &opt, &optlen);
```

This way, `getsockopt()` knows how much it's allowed to write into the "buffer", which in this case is just an integer, and it updates `optlen` with the number of bytes it actually wrote.

The man page notes this that `optlen` is a value/result, which means you set it going in and expect to get another value back, but `opt` is a result only so doesn't care what the value going in is.

**EDIT** fixed the type of optlen to `socklen_t`, with h/t to prog-fh

Answer (score 3):

When using `getsockopt()` the last parameter must be the address of
an **initialised** `socklen_t`.
Before the call you should initialise it with the size of the storage
to obtain the resulting value (`sizeof(opt)` here).
It is passed by address because if this storage is too large
for the actual result, then the system call adjusts it to this
exact size.